# Using custom wrappers for inputs: pros and cons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Often there are times when I need to have totally custom input elements: checkboxes, radio buttons, selects, etc.

Just wanted to ask if such practice is okay and acceptable:

1. we create some sort of wrapper for our input (radio box in this case)
2. we hide our real radio boxes(opacity: 0, visibility: hidden, left: -9999px, etc)
3. On click on a parent wrapper: we get the input name attribute, find all inputs with [type="radio][name="clickedInputName"], set them all to become unchecked and set the one we clicked to set it to checked.

Attaching some *not quite beautiful* jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/moLvh9dd/

```
    $('.radio-wrapper').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var targetInput = $(this).find($('input'));

var clickedInputName = 'input[type="radio"]    [name="'+targetInput.attr('name')+'"]';

$(clickedInputName).each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
    $(this).parent().removeClass('input-checked');
})

targetInput.prop('checked', true); 
$(this).addClass('input-checked');

});
```

Checked the browser compatibility, + - works everywhere down to IE8, so despite the fact that it just works I want to know if it's the right way? Is it acceptable?`

Despite the fact that it's javascript/jQuery dependent.

EDIT:

Thanks for some great answers on radio and checkbox inputs but what about custom select element? With various amount of options for every select?

For example like here - some ugly jQuery again: https://jsfiddle.net/4gt7gavq/

Comment: The actual form elements themselves are plain HTML meaning they are still accessible to and usable by those without JavaScript enabled. However, they do still appear off screen which could cause issues so I would suggest adding the `.radio-wrapper` class dynamically with JS, on page load.

Comment: Another suggestion, to avoid JS altogether, would be to use labels instead of spans, apply your pseudo-classes to them, place your inputs off screen and then use the `:checked` psuedo class & adjacent selectors to change the styles of the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow an alternative without using JS with pure CSS or using images.
In here you can find both techniques explained, i would advise the pure CSS way of course but that depends on your cross-browser requirements.

**Pure CSS styling**

The demonstration below is styled purely using CSS. Unlike the image-based method, the pure CSS method scales with the text size.
The HTML used for each checkbox or radio button is similar to that in the image-based method:

```
<div>
  <input id="option" type="checkbox" name="field" value="option">
  <label for="option"><span><span></span></span>Value</label>
</div>
```

The span elements inside the label are used to create the alternative graphics. While radio buttons require both spans, only one is needed for checkboxes.

We hide the checkboxes and radio buttons in the stylesheet:

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(old),
input[type=radio   ]:not(old){
  width     : 2em;
  margin    : 0;
  padding   : 0;
  font-size : 1em;
  opacity   : 0;
}
```

The technique is the same as in the image-based method, but because the width is set relative to the font size in line 3 we must restore the font size in line 6, as browsers use a smaller font size for checkboxes and radio buttons by default.

We then position the label:

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label{
  display      : inline-block;
  margin-left  : -2em;
  line-height  : 1.5em;
}
```

Again, the technique is the same as in the image-based method, but using relative units. The padding is not required as the scalable graphics, unlike a background image, will push the label text along.

We then style the first span to create the unchecked graphics:

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label > span,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label > span{
  display          : inline-block;
  width            : 0.875em;
  height           : 0.875em;
  margin           : 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0.25em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(192,192,192);
  border-radius    : 0.25em;
  background       : rgb(224,224,224);
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  vertical-align   : bottom;
}
```

The techniques used here are described in detail in the page on styling buttons with CSS3. Line 15 ensures the graphics are positioned at the bottom of the label rather than the baseline of the text.

In the example, the background gradient is reversed on selected checkboxes and radio buttons:

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label > span,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old):checked + label > span{
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
}
```

We then display a tick inside selected checkboxes:

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label > span:before{
  content     : '✓';
  display     : block;
  width       : 1em;
  color       : rgb(153,204,102);
  font-size   : 0.875em;
  line-height : 1em;
  text-align  : center;
  text-shadow : 0 0 0.0714em rgb(115,153,77);
  font-weight : bold;
}
```

The selector in line 1 uses the :before pseudo-class so that line 2 can insert a tick symbol inside the span element. Lines 3, 4, 6, 7, and 8 display the tick centrally within the element, while lines 5, 9, and 10 style the text.

Finally, we display a ‘bullet’ inside selected radio buttons, applying the same techniques as for the unchecked graphics to the second span element:

```
input[type=radio]:not(old):checked + label > span > span{
  display          : block;
  width            : 0.5em;
  height           : 0.5em;
  margin           : 0.125em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(115,153,77);
  border-radius    : 0.125em;
  background       : rgb(153,204,102);
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
}
```

http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/#pureCSS

**Select** element

On the select element you can change colors, borders and the drop-down arrow. Not much more.

To do this create a png with the custom arrow and set it as element brackground:

```
.styled-select {
   width: 240px;
   height: 34px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url(new_arrow.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   }
```

http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Comment: Thanks, @Bolza, this seems to work but then the next level appears - what about the <select> element? I'm not sure if i can edit the post and add additional information but i also have fully custom <select> element made with javascript/jQuery just like these inputs. I guess this one wouldn't turn out without js.

Just don't know if it's the right way.

Comment: I added some info on the select element inside the answer

Comment: @Bolza, see the following with regard to referencing: http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: Well i'm not sure what i should change: i put the link to all the references and i quoted the entire "CSS" part of the first article because that seemed the "relevant portion". Should i remove most of that quoted part?

Comment: @Bolza , what do you think about this way? https://jsfiddle.net/4gt7gavq/

Ugly, but it works.

Comment: Well @DaumantasJakas of course you can still make a JS wrapper (and in this case i don't really see why using JQuery if you havent already imported it in other parts of your code) but you asked for an alternative way of styling inputs. That's the way using CSS alone. Of course it has some limitation in respect of a JS solution that is much more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

These practices are very much acceptable. For the most part, as long as the form is still accessible and usable with JavaScript and/or CSS disabled, you're OK.

To expand on one of my comments above with some sample code for the example provided in the original question, you can achieve this through CSS alone, without any need for JavaScript.

What you need to do is use labels with pseudo elements and then use the `:checked` pseudo class with an adjacent selector to change the styles of those pseudo elements.

- [More information on adjacent selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)
- [More information on the `:checked` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

This has the added benefit of requiring less markup, as well, but that will depend on your overall layout.

Here's the sample code:

```css
*,*:before,*:after{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;}
input.radio{
    left:-9999px;
    position:absolute;
}
label.radio{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    line-height:20px;
    margin:0 0 10px;
    padding:0 0 0 26px;
    position:relative;
}
label.radio:before{
    border:1px solid #f00;
    border-radius:50%;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:16px;
    left:5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    width:16px;
}
label.radio:after{
    background:#f00;
    border-radius:50%;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:8px;
    left:9px;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:6px;
    transform:scale(0);
    transition:transform .25s,opacity .5s;
    width:8px;
}
input.radio:checked+label.radio:after{
    opacity:1;
    transform:scale(1);
}
```

```html
<input class="radio" name="radio-option" id="option1" type="radio" value="1">
<label class="radio" for="option1">Option 1</label>
<input class="radio" name="radio-option" id="option2" type="radio" value="2">
<label class="radio" for="option2">Option 2</label>
<input class="radio" name="radio-option" id="option3" type="radio" value="3">
<label class="radio" for="option3">Option 3</label>
<input class="radio" name="radio-option" id="option4" type="radio" value="4">
<label class="radio" for="option4">Option 4</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a drawback of replacing the original input element, you will lose the ability to focus and change the value of this element with the keyboard ([tabindex](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-tabindex)).